# Text animation doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

the bar with text on this website users.telenet.be/stijn.aerts should change after every 5 seconds. The problem is that it doesnt work in IE, it works in other browsers...

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: "`Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.`"

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is not applying the opacity rules of the parent to the absolutely positioned children . In this case, you're setting the opacity of the list items, but this isn't cascading down onto absolutely-positioned h2 elements within.

One work around that you can use is to set the position of the parenting list item elements to relative. This causes the opacity declarations to cascade down and affect even the absolutely positioned children.

```css
ul.textslideshow li {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    animation: textAnimation 25s ease-out infinite;
}
```

If you wish not to position the parenting list item, you can set opacity to inherit on the headings:

```css
ul.textslideshow li h2 {
    opacity: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    /*...*/
}
```

Example of issue in Internet Explorer: http://jsfiddle.net/xTG85/show/
Example of issue resolved in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/xTG85/1/show/